# Makefile:12: *** missing separator. Stop

Tags: compiling, make, c++

In trying to compile my `makefile`, I keep getting the same error message repeatedly:

```
Makefile:12: *** missing separator. Stop
```

I've removed the tabs, removed the spaces, deleted the `makefile` entirely and tried all over but I still get the same message. Please help.

```makefile
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -std=c++11
TARGET = proj1.x
SOURCES = driver.cpp
    
proj1.x: driver.cpp
    g++ -std=c++11 -o proj1.x driver.cpp
        
.PHONY: clean
   
clean:
    rm -f proj1.x
```

Comment: The most common reason for this error is using spaces rather than tabs to indent recipes - check the `clean` recipe in particular

Answer (score 5):

As written in [a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/769126/makefile12-missing-separator-stop#comment1468336_769126), the problem here is almost certainly that you are not using <kbd>Tab</kbd> to indent the recipe instructions in your `Makefile`. You mention that, "*I've removed the tabs*", and this is a problem.

Converting your file to use tabs (not indents with other whitespace, but proper tabs, ASCII character 9), I confirmed that in my case the described error went away:

```sh
# Your makefile
make
  makefile:7: *** missing separator.  Stop.

# Convert indents to tab
mv -f makefile{,.old} && sed -E 's/^ {3,}/\t/' makefile.old >makefile

# Retry your makefile
make
  g++ -std=c++11 -o proj1.x driver.cpp
  […]
```